# Javascipt not working in Samsung Internet Browser

Tags: javascript, android

I am working in angular project have below function

```
isNumber(evt) {
    evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
    let charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
    if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
```

and in HTML

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="abc" name="abc"
            formControlName="abc" maxlength="4" pattern="\d[0-9]+"(keypress)="isNumber($event)"/>
```

It works on all browsers except in the Samsung internet browser in Android phones. It still accepting alphabets which I do not want. Please help me with this. Thanks in advance

Comment: Why doesn't it work? What's the problem with this code? Do you get any errors? Does something not work, in which case what and what happens instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"If you're having trouble accessing webpages or getting errors about Javascript on your mobile device or tablet, see the steps below on how to enable Javascript in Samsung Internet Browser..."

Have you tried to turn on JavaScript like Samsung explains it: https://www.samsung.com/au/support/mobile-devices/how-do-i-turn-on-javascript/